# read struct objects from a file and point to the object read using void* pointer

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, void-pointers

I have the following four structs in my program

```
struct SType{
    int type;//struct type
};

struct S1{
};

struct S2{
};

struct S3{
};
```

I am saving the states of these structs in a file using the following code:

> void store(struct SType s1,void *s){
>
> ```
> //open file and stuff
> //s points to either one of the last three structs
> fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),1,file);  fwrite(s, size, 1, file);
> //structs are always saved in the file in pairs of SType and either one of the last three structs 
> }
> ```

Now when i am trying to retrieve the second struct of the pair from the file using the following code, i get segmentation fault. So how do i retreive an object of an arbitary struct type using fread()?

```
void read(){
void *record;
//read struct SType object from the file 
//now read the second struct of the pair   
fread(record,size,1,file);
}
```

Comment: We need more code. My *guess* is that you haven't allocated memory to read the `struct` into. It's good to reduce your code so as not to "spam" everybody, but a small working example of the erroneous code would be perfect (rather than psuedocode)

Comment: @noelicus i want to read the struct or rather a reference to it into a void * pointer....when i am reading the struct, the struct object read can be a type of either s1,s2 or s3....later on in my code i will typecast the void* pointer into the appropriate struct type pointer.

Comment: My point is that you have `read` *into valid memory*, and I was guessing that you may not have done that. I had to guess because you didn't include the code, which was my other point!!

Comment: @noelicus i did include the `read` code and i am reading into a void *pointer(the last code part of the question)..your comment actually did give me an idea..i allocated memory to the `void* record` using `malloc(sizeof(void)` which successfully read the first record but now i am getting a segmentation fault while reading the second pair of the records.

Comment: OK. That's useful to know. It looks like you've missed code out (which is your problem, in fact!!) - will add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read into valid memory. `void` means "I don't know" and the system cannot and will not guess that value for you!!
What you have is:

```
void read(){
void *record;// This pointer currently is a random value - this will cause a fault when you try and copy data into it by calling:
fread(record,size,1,file);
}
```

It should be:

```
void read(){
void *record;
len = ?; // Your program needs to know this. You must know which structure it is somehow if you are to cast it later. Therefore you should know its size.
record = malloc(len); // Where len has been previously found to be AT LEAST big enough to read into
fread(record,size,1,file);
}
```

As you say your code is not psuedocode, then also put something in your structs so they're not empty. It would also be advisable to do something with the structure once you've read it, for example return the void * from your fread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx it worked...`void *pointer=malloc(sizeof(void))` was reading the entire file irrespective of the `size to be read` provided in the `fread(pointer,size,1,file)` function..and yes i didnt provide the actual code..i just provided the actual syntax used to read and write since i thought that would be enough

Answer (score 1):

You read a record to uninitialized pointer, I guess you should alloc memory first.

```
void *record = maloc( size )
```

And do not forget to free ...

May I suggest you to use a Union?

Your type definitions will look like this:

```
struct SType{
    int type;//struct type
};
struct S1{
};

struct S2{
};

struct S3{
};

union S{
    S1 s1;
    S2 s2;
    S3 s3;
};
```

now read and write can be done like this:

```
SType stype;
S s;

fread(&stype,sizeof(stype),1,file);
size = ???  //get according to type
fread(&s,size,1,file); 
// your data will be stored according to type in s.s1, s.s2 or s.s3   

size = ???  //get according to type
fwrite(&stype,sizeof(stype),1,file);
fwrite(&s,size,1,file);
```

Next stage, is to unify the Type with the rest:

```
struct S{
    int type;//struct type
    union {
        S1 s1;
        S2 s2;
        S3 s3;
    }s;
};
/* in case you don't care about loosing file space, 
   you can read\write all in a single operation like this:
 */ 
S s;
fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,file); 
// now according to the type you take s.s.s1, s.s.s2 or s.s.s3.   
fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,file);

/* if you do care about loosing file space, you work like before */
S s;
fread(&s.type,sizeof(int),1,file);
size = ??? //get according to type
fread(&s.s,size,1,file); 
// as before, you take s.s.s1, s.s.s2 or s.s.s3.   
size = ???  //get according to type
fwrite(&s.type,sizeof(int),1,file);
fwrite(&s.s,size,1,file);
```